# create Charts with non-adjacent rows google apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want the graph to have the first line as names, and the values of each column to be the values of line 6, but the getRange method only takes adjacent values. In the example graph, place the getRange with row 1 and row 2. However, with row 6,  I've created a function but I got an error (Exception: Argument cannot be null: a1Notation). I have been unable to solve the problem for several days.

```
function colChart1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.newChart()               
    .asColumnChart()
    .addRange(sheet.getRange(rangeNonAdjacent())) 
    .addRange(sheet.getRange(1,1,2,4)) 
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
    .build();
    sheet.insertChart(chart);
}

function rangeNonAdjacent(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
  var data = [];
  var ranges = ss.getRangeList(["A1:D1","A6:D6"]).getRanges();
    for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++){
    data = data.concat(ranges[i].getValues()); }
  //return data;
  console.log(data);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script and sample Spreadsheet, how about the following modification? In this case, `setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)` is used.

#### Modified script:

```js
function colChart1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .asColumnChart()
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:D1"))
    .addRange(sheet.getRange("A6:D6"))
    .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', false)
    .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

- If you want to use the last row of "A6:D6" by retrieving a script, please modify the above script as follows.

  - From

    ```
      .addRange(sheet.getRange("A6:D6"))
    ```
  - To

    ```
      .addRange(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()))
    ```

    or

    ```
      .addRange(sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, 4))
    ```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [setMergeStrategy(mergeStrategy)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setMergeStrategy(ChartMergeStrategy))

Comment: It worked Perfectly. You are the best. I hope you can help me with others questions. Thank you.

Comment: @NIN Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I hope you can help me with others questions.`, when I saw your posted questions, I would like to confirm it.